# Android - admob and SurfaceView issue

Tags: android, admob, surfaceview

i am trying to start using admob, but it seems to be harder than i thought.
I just wanted to write a little test app, in which i would draw something on a surface view and add an admob example to it.

in my main activity i do the following in the onCreate method:

the AndroidFastRenderView is my implementation of SurfaceView.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        boolean isLandscape = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

        int frameBufferWidth = isLandscape ? 480 : 320;
        int frameBufferHeight = isLandscape ? 270 : 430;

        Bitmap frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBufferWidth,
                frameBufferHeight, Config.RGB_565);


        renderView = new AndroidFastRenderView(this, frameBuffer);
        graphics = new AndroidGraphics(getAssets(), frameBuffer);

        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "XXX");
        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams gameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams adsParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        layout.addView(adView, 0, adsParams);

        layout.addView(renderView, 1, gameParams);
        setContentView(layout);


        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

When i do this, the whole screen is filled with the AndroidFastRenderView.
However, when i do not add the AndroidFastRenderView the ad appears.
So i think the problem is that, maybe the AndroidFastRenderView is drawn above my ad(maybe i did something wrong with the size of my framebuffer) or that the AndroidFastRenderView "steals" the space of the ad.

i hope you understand what my problem is and that anyone can help me solve my problem

yours, Lukas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a RelativeLayout instead of a FrameLayout?

```
final int adId = 0x12345;
adView.setId(adId);
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams =
    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gameParams =
    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
gameParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, adId);
layout.addView(adView, adParams);
layout.addView(renderView, gameParams);
setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: i dont´t no why, but it works :)
thank you very much, that problem already cost me some hours and would have cost me many more without your help, thanks!